# Are addTransaction and addItem totally separate from each other in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, transactions, e-commerce

I'm using Google Analytics with an ecommerce site and the data is being sent to GA, which is cool, and I'm looking in the Conversions > Ecommerce > Transactions section. When I click on a Transaction ID to view it, it doesn't show the individual items that I know where in that transaction but it shows the revenue. But then I noticed that further down the line, there are other Transaction ID's that when I open up, display the individual item or product info without any revenue tied to it.

It's like the data that is part of addItem is completely separate from addTransaction, even when looking at the reporting results. I assumed that the transaction was a parent element and all of the items purchased within that transaction were child elements and it would display/report that way.

Is there a way to mesh these together so that I can view the transaction ID with all of it's child items?

Comment: please add you code used at the transaction place in your web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are only using `ecommerce:addItem` in you site code, when you also need to specify the total in an `ecommerce:addTransaction` tag.

If you only call `ecommerce:addItem`, Google will automatically create a blank transaction (with no total amount) based on the transaction_id required in addItem.

[From Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce?hl=en):

> Note: While most implementations will send both transaction and item data, you can send transactions without items, and items without transactions. If you send an item hit without a transaction, a transaction hit with only the ID will be sent automatically.

Transactions are not just the automatic sum of Items because some charges (like tax, shipping, or even "gift-wrap" for example) might need to be added to the total at the transaction level, but don't correspond to individual items.

As long as you ensure you fire both `ecommerce:addItem` calls and `ecommerce:addTransaction` calls using the same transaction `id` before you fire `ga('ecommerce:send');`, everything should show up in Google Analytics the way you are hoping.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. Right now I have both `ecommerce:addItem` and `ecommerce:addTransaction` but they are both using separate ID's so maybe that's why the items are being split out from the parent transaction and treated as their own in reporting.

Comment: oh that would do it, use the same ID. If you need separate ids for items you can use SKU.

Comment: That was the deal. Each item being added to the cart has it's own item ID along with SKU and category so by dropping the item ID in `ecommerce:addItem` and replacing it with the transaction ID, the data is reporting the way it should now. Thanks!